# Access VBA: Set conditional format on duplicate text values

Tags: ms-access, vba

my first question here but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.
I have created a report on which colleagues can see appointments booked by users.
But my colleagues would like to have a clear view of users with the same lastname so no appointments get mixed.

Example:
Joe Smith is booked at 15 o'clock.
Jane Smith is booked at 10 o'clock.
I would like to have the lastname Smith underlined/bold so the name "pops" while checking the list.

I've found some info regarding DCount but can't seem to be able to put it to use. I thought perhaps a Match-function might also work, but I can't specify cells of the Access report.
So I hope you guys can help me further.
Thanks anyway!

EDIT:
Here is a small screenshot, the name should be highlighted when it appears more than once in the report.
[AccessReport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nooOG.png)

Comment: This question is too broad

Comment: Generally I'd add a field to the report source query that can be quantified by the _Conditional Formatting_ rules - something that would result in a count or a true/false statement.  I'd then add a control to the back of the report (right-click/position/send to back) that shows this figure and has the conditional formatting attached.  Without any more info it's a bit hard to give an specifics though - so as Rafael said.

Comment: Hi, what more information do you need? I can't provide too much due to confidentiality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the DCount you need.
`Nz(DCount("*","[table]","[LastNameField] = '" & [LastNameField] & "'"),0)>1`

I made a test database real quick to verify this worked.  It goes in the conditional formatting expression.  Just replace the table and field names to what you are using.

[image: Formatted Report]

Comment: Hi, if I try that then all records are highlighted.
My report is based on a query, should I enter the query name in the code then?
Because when I try that the conditional format isn't working.

Comment: When I enter the following expression nothing happens: Nz(DCount("*";"[qryDZG]";"[Naam Patiënt] = '" & [Naam Patiënt] & "'");0)>1

When I try with the table name then all fields are highlighted: Nz(DCount("*";"[dbo_Opnames]";"[Naam Patiënt] = '" & [Naam Patiënt] & "'");0)>1
When I remove the 'dbo_' from the expression then, again, nothing happens:
Nz(DCount("*";"[Opnames]";"[Naam Patiënt] = '" & [Naam Patiënt] & "'");0)>1

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Is it because the report isn't based on a table but on a query?